# solaris : useradd does not work but has exit code 0

Tags: user-management, solaris-10

One of my Solaris 10 servers will not add new users. Existing users are able to log in.

The useradd command appears to work normally but it does not add the user. I checked my other Solaris servers and verified file permissions on /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow are the same.

```
# useradd -s /bin/bash -m testuser
# echo $?
0
# passwd testuser
passwd: User unknown: testuser
Permission denied
# grep -i testuser /etc/passwd
# ls -lh /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--   1 root     sys          779 Oct  6  2012 /etc/passwd
# ls -lh /etc/shadow
-r--------   1 root     sys          385 Nov 13 13:50 /etc/shadow
```

As suggested by jlliagre:

```
# type useradd
useradd is /usr/sbin/useradd
# useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testuser -m testuser
# passwd testuser
passwd: User unknown: testuser
Permission denied
```

I also tried useradd with no args:

```
# useradd testuser
# passwd testuser
passwd: User unknown: testuser
Permission denied
```

I just noticed this too. Each time I ran `useradd -m`, the home directories did get created, all with user id 50011.

```
 # ls -lth /home/ | head -6
 total 36
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 19:37 webbtest
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 19:36 webb3
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 19:27 webb
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 14:56 testuser
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 14:46 test_user
```

Thanks for the suggestions so far, [guys](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/guys). I have added users to at least a dozen other Solaris boxes without running into this.

As requested by jlliagre:

```
# df -k /home;ls -l@ /usr/sbin/useradd; pkgchk SUNWcsu; grep passwd: /etc/nsswitch.conf
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s6    20646961  604690 19835802     3%    /home
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root     sys        40252 Jul  6  2011 /usr/sbin/useradd
passwd:     files ldap

# useradd -s /bin/bash -b /export/home -m testuser
UX: useradd: ERROR: invalid syntax.
usage:  useradd [-u uid [-o] | -g group | -G group[[,group]...] |-d dir |
                -s shell | -c comment | -m [-k skel_dir] | -f inactive |
                -e expire | -A authorization [, authorization ...] |
                -P profile [, profile ...] | -R role [, role ...] |
                -K key=value | -p project [, project ...]] login
        useradd -D [-g group | -b base_dir | -f inactive | -e expire
                -A authorization [, authorization ...] |
                -P profile [, profile ...] | -R role [, role ...] |
                -K key=value ... -p project]
```

Truss output:

```
# userdel testuser
UX: userdel: ERROR: testuser does not exist.
# truss -t\!memcntl,getuid,door_call,door_info,close,mmap,brk,munmap,lwp_sigmask,sigaction,llseek -f useradd -m -d /tmp/testuser testuser
1064:   execve("/usr/sbin/useradd", 0xFFBFFCC4, 0xFFBFFCDC)  argc = 5
1064:   sysinfo(SI_MACHINE, "sun4v", 257)               = 6
1064:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/ld.so.1", "/lib/ld.so.1", 1023) = 12
1064:   resolvepath("/usr/sbin/useradd", "/usr/sbin/useradd", 1023) = 17
1064:   stat64("/usr/sbin/useradd", 0xFFBFF790)         = 0
1064:   open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1064:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFF300)                          = 0
1064:   stat64("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)        = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", "/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 1023) = 18
1064:   open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libproject.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)      Err#2 ENOENT
1064:   stat64("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)  = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", "/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", 1023) = 24
1064:   open("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)            = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libc.so.1", "/lib/libc.so.1", 1023) = 14
1064:   open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libnsl.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libnsl.so.1", "/lib/libnsl.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libcmd.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libcmd.so.1", "/lib/libcmd.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libproc.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)         = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libproc.so.1", "/lib/libproc.so.1", 1023) = 17
1064:   open("/lib/libproc.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)      = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", "/lib/librtld_db.so.1", 1023) = 20
1064:   open("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libelf.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libelf.so.1", "/lib/libelf.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libctf.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libctf.so.1", "/lib/libctf.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libctf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   getcontext(0xFFBFF600)
1064:   getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, 0xFFBFF5E0)             = 0
1064:   getpid()                                        = 1064 [1063]
1064:   setustack(0xFF0B2A88)
1064:   sigfillset(0xFF31B3BC)                          = 0
1064:   stat64("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFEA90) = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 1023) = 33
1064:   open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
1064:   sysconfig(_CONFIG_PAGESIZE)                     = 8192
1064:   open("/usr/sadm/defadduser", O_RDONLY)          = 3
1064:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFE768)                          = 0
1064:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFE610)                          = 0
1064:   ioctl(3, TCGETA, 0xFFBFE6F4)                    Err#25 ENOTTY
1064:   read(3, " #\t D e f a u l t   v a".., 8192)     = 286
1064:   read(3, 0x0002B23C, 8192)                       = 0
1064:   getpid()                                        = 1064 [1063]
1064:   open("/proc/1064/psinfo", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1064:   read(3, "02\0\0\0\0\0\001\0\004 (".., 336)      = 336
1064:   open64("/var/run/name_service_door", O_RDONLY)  = 3
1064:   fcntl(3, F_SETFD, 0x00000001)                   = 0
1064:   stat("/tmp/testuser", 0xFFBFEBB8)               = 0
1064:   schedctl()                                      = 0xFF330000
1064:   fork1()                                         = 1065
1065:   fork1()         (returning as child ...)        = 1064
1065:   getpid()                                        = 1065 [1064]
1065:   lwp_self()                                      = 1
1065:   open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 1
1065:   open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 2
1065:   execve("/usr/bin/passmgmt", 0x0002B670, 0x0002C0F4)  argc = 29
1065:   sysinfo(SI_MACHINE, "sun4v", 257)               = 6
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/sbin/passmgmt", "/usr/sbin/passmgmt", 1023) = 18
1065:   stat64("/usr/sbin/passmgmt", 0xFFBFF680)        = 0
1065:   open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1065:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFF1F0)                          = 0
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)        = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", "/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 1023) = 18
1065:   open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/passwdutil.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)      Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)  = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", "/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", 1023) = 24
1065:   open("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)            = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libc.so.1", "/lib/libc.so.1", 1023) = 14
1065:   open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/libnsl.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libnsl.so.1", "/lib/libnsl.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/libcmd.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libcmd.so.1", "/lib/libcmd.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1065:   getcontext(0xFFBFF4F0)
1065:   getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, 0xFFBFF4D0)             = 0
1065:   getpid()                                        = 1065 [1064]
1065:   setustack(0xFF362A88)
1065:   sigfillset(0xFF31B3BC)                          = 0
1065:   stat64("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFE980) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 1023) = 33
1065:   open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
1065:   time()                                          = 1384439953
1065:   open("/var/run/tzsync", O_RDONLY)               = 3
1065:   open("/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/US/Eastern", O_RDONLY) = 3
1065:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFF4A0)                          = 0
1065:   read(3, " T Z i f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".., 1267)     = 1267
1065:   creat("/etc/.pwd.lock", 0600)                   = 3
1065:   fcntl(3, F_SETLK, 0xFF3159D0)                   = 0
1065:   getpid()                                        = 1065 [1064]
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsldap.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)        Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)    = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", "/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", 1023) = 22
1065:   open("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", O_RDONLY)        = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libldap.so.5", 0xFFBFE8A0)         Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", 0xFFBFE8A0)     = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", "/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", 1023) = 21
1065:   open("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", O_RDONLY)         = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libscf.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libscf.so.1", "/lib/libscf.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libscf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libdoor.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)         = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libdoor.so.1", "/lib/libdoor.so.1", 1023) = 17
1065:   open("/lib/libdoor.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)    Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libuutil.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)        = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libuutil.so.1", "/lib/libuutil.so.1", 1023) = 18
1065:   open("/lib/libuutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libgen.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libgen.so.1", "/lib/libgen.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libgen.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libsocket.so.1", 0xFFBFE598) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsocket.so.1", 0xFFBFE598)       = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libsocket.so.1", "/lib/libsocket.so.1", 1023) = 19
1065:   open("/lib/libsocket.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnsl.so.1", 0xFFBFE598)  Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libmp.so.2", 0xFFBFE980)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libmp.so.2", "/lib/libmp.so.2", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/libmp.so.2", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libmd.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libmd.so.1", "/lib/libmd.so.1", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/libmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libsasl.so.1", 0xFFBFE980) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsasl.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)         Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)     = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", "/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", 1023) = 21
1065:   open("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 4
1065:   stat64("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFE4C8) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", 1023) = 34
1065:   open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libmd.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)   Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", 0xFFBFE980)  = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", 1023) = 24
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libpthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)      = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libpthread.so.1", "/lib/libpthread.so.1", 1023) = 20
1065:   open("/lib/libpthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/librt.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/librt.so.1", "/lib/librt.so.1", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libdl.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libdl.so.1", "/lib/libdl.so.1", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/libdl.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libaio.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libaio.so.1", "/lib/libaio.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
1065:   sysinfo(SI_ISALIST, "sparcv9 sparcv8plus sparcv8 sparcv8-fsmuld sparcv7 sparc sparcv9+vis sparcv9+vis2 sparcv8plus+vis sparcv8plus+vis2", 257) = 115
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv9/libnspr_flt4.so", 0xFFBFE4C8) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", 0xFFBFE4C8) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", 1023) = 44
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", 0xFFBFE980)   = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", 1023) = 23
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", 0xFFBFE980)   = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", 1023) = 23
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", 0xFFBFE8A0) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", 1023) = 27
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", O_RDONLY)   = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", 0xFFBFE8A0)  = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", 1023) = 24
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/secv1/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", 0xFFBFE980)   = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", 1023) = 23
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/secv1/libthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)       = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libthread.so.1", "/lib/libthread.so.1", 1023) = 19
1065:   open("/lib/libthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/librt.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)   Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/secv1/librt.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   write(2, " l d . s o . 1 :   p a s".., 130)     = 130
1065:   write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
1065:   lwp_self()                                      = 1
1064:   waitid(P_ALL, 0, 0xFFBFE980, WEXITED|WTRAPPED)  = 0
1064:   _exit(0)
```

ldd /usr/sbin/passmgmt /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1; pkgchk SUNWtls1

```
# ldd /usr/sbin/passmgmt /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1                 
/usr/sbin/passmgmt:
        libsecdb.so.1 =>         /lib/libsecdb.so.1
        passwdutil.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
        libsldap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libsldap.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnspr4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
        libplc4.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so
        libnss3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so
        libssl3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libnssutil3.so =>        /usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so
        libthread.so.1 =>        /lib/libthread.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so
/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1:
        libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
        libsldap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libsldap.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnspr4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
        libplc4.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so
        libnss3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so
        libssl3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libnssutil3.so =>        /usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so
        libthread.so.1 =>        /lib/libthread.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so
# pkgchk SUNWtls1
WARNING: no pathnames were associated with <SUNWtls1>
```

set|grep LD;crle;truss -w2 -ft open useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testuser -m testuser

```
# set|grep LD;crle;truss -w2 -ft open useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testuser -m testuser

Configuration file [version 4]: /var/ld/ld.config
  Platform:     32-bit MSB SPARC
  Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib
  Trusted Directories (ELF):    /lib/secure:/usr/lib/secure  (system default)

Command line:
  crle -c /var/ld/ld.config -l /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib

922:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
922:    open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
922:    open("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
922:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
922:    open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/lib/libproc.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 3
922:    open("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 3
922:    open("/lib/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/lib/libctf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
922:    open("/usr/sadm/defadduser", O_RDONLY)          = 3
922:    open("/proc/922/psinfo", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open64("/var/run/name_service_door", O_RDONLY)  = 3
923:    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 1
923:    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 2
923:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
923:    open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
923:    open("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
923:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
923:    open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
923:    open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
923:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
923:    open("/var/run/tzsync", O_RDONLY)               = 3
923:    open("/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/US/Eastern", O_RDONLY) = 3
923:    open("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", O_RDONLY)        = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", O_RDONLY)         = 4
923:    open("/lib/libscf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
923:    open("/lib/libdoor.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 4
923:    open("/lib/libuutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 4
923:    open("/lib/libgen.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
923:    open("/lib/libsocket.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
923:    open("/lib/libmp.so.2", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/lib/libmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 4
923:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
923:    open("/lib/libpthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 4
923:    open("/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/lib/libdl.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/lib/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", O_RDONLY)   = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
923:    open("/lib/libthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
923:    write(2, 0xFF3FC74C, 130)                       = 130
923:       l d . s o . 1 :   p a s s m g m t :   f a t a l :   r e l o c a
923:       t i o n   e r r o r :   f i l e   / u s r / s b i n / p a s s m
923:       g m t :   s y m b o l   _ _ p w u _ l o c k i n g _ r e s t r i
923:       c t i v e :   r e f e r e n c e d   s y m b o l   n o t   f o u
923:       n d
923:    write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
925:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
925:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
925:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
925:    open("/lib/libsec.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
925:    open("/lib/libavl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
925:    open("/lib/libcmdutils.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 3
925:    open64("/etc/skel/.profile", O_RDONLY)          = 4
925:    open64("/etc/skel/local.cshrc", O_RDONLY)       = 4
925:    open64("/etc/skel/local.login", O_RDONLY)       = 4
925:    open64("/etc/skel/local.profile", O_RDONLY)     = 4
927:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
927:    open("/lib/libcmdutils.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 3
927:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
927:    open("/lib/libavl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
927:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
#
# passmgmt
ld.so.1: passmgmt: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/sbin/passmgmt: symbol __pwu_locking_restrictive: referenced symbol not found
Killed
#
```

pkgchk SUNWcsl SUNWcslr SUNWdpl SUNWlibms SUNWlibmsr SUNWlibsasl SUNWpr SUNWtls

```
# pkgchk SUNWcsl SUNWcslr SUNWdpl SUNWlibms SUNWlibmsr SUNWlibsasl SUNWpr SUNWtls
WARNING: no pathnames were associated with <SUNWdpl>
```

ldd -dp /usr/bin/passmgmt

```
# ldd -dp /usr/bin/passmgmt
        libsecdb.so.1 =>         /lib/libsecdb.so.1
        passwdutil.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
        libsldap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libsldap.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnspr4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
        libplc4.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so
        libnss3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so
        libssl3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libnssutil3.so =>        /usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so
        libthread.so.1 =>        /lib/libthread.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so
```